# Android runtime error when using a button to change activities

Tags: android, runtime-error

in MainActivity.java (where the button is i want to click and move to the DrinksActivity)

```
public void calculate(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, DrinksActivity.class));
}
```

button xml for MainActivity:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/genderbutton"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
    android:onClick="calculate"
    android:text="@string/next2"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

DrinksActivity in manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.bac.DrinksActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_drinks" >
</activity>
```

the DrinksActivity.java is currently just the basic. no changes have been made.

The app will run perfectly fine, but when I click on the button I get a runtime error that stops the app and will not transfer to the DrinksActivity.

Logcat file:

```
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bac/com.example.bac.DrinksActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.bac:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{4190fdc0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.bac:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{4190fdc0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:930)
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1163)
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5018)
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2032)
09-22 02:16:32.677: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  ... 11 more
09-22 02:16:34.947: I/Process(615): Sending signal. PID: 615 SIG: 9
```

I also had one other question that you may be able to help me with (not pertaining to this question) how do you make it so the app can just be scrolled downward by touch and have a longer activity?

DrinksActivity class:

```
package com.example.bac;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class DrinksActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drinks);

     if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drinks, menu);
    return true;
}

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drinks, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

placeholder fragment in main activity:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

drinks.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.bac.DrinksActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hmd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/hmd"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dyh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hmd"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/dyh"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/wine"
        android:layout_below="@+id/wine"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:text="@string/shots"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/beer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/beer"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:text="@string/wine"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/shotinput"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/shot"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/shot"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/wineinput"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="#"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorLink="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/drinksbutton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="62dp"
        android:onClick="next"
        android:text="@string/next1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hmd"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dyh"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="@string/beer"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/beerinput"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/beer"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/beer"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shot"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="#"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorLink="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/wineinput"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/wine"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/wine"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/beerinput"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="#"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorLink="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post `DrinksActivity`

Comment: can you paste placeholder fragment here

Comment: Post DrinksActivity and view

Comment: you need a container to attach fragment to the activity. The container can be a view group such as a `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`

Comment: You cannot start fragment as a activity

Comment: ummm so you have the same layout in your Activity AND Framgent... what's up with that

Comment: I added what was requested and I don't understand what you mean Raghunandan how do i make the container to to attach the fragment and then make the code?

Comment: post your drinks.xml

it should contain a framelayout with id as content

Comment: @bobshishka : u don't have any Layout(FrameLayout or RelativeLayout)  with id `container` in `drinks` xml

Comment: The exception indicates you're trying to add the fragment to a container (`R.id.container`) that is not present in the layout (`R.layout.drinks`). Not sure what you mean with your second question, but sounds like you may be looking for the `ScrollView` widget (or ListView/GridView for large data sets).

Comment: does anyone know how I can fix this so that clicking the button takes me to the drinks page....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem arise from this two lines

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
}
```

Every Fragment needs a "container" that is used by the activity to host the Fragment itself. This container is usually one of the implementation of `ViewGroup` provided by the framework (`FrameLayout` i.e.). What your code is saying is that you have declared a View with id `R.id.container`, inside `R.layout.drinks`, which, given the exception, is not the case

Comment: declare `R.id.container` into `R.layout.drinks` or get rid of those two lines (if you are not using the fragment, or you don't want to)

Comment: wow you are really good sir... you deserve all the rep on this site. Thank you for clearing that massive headache. (I've only been android programming for a week. I've learned java programming, C++ and Mips before this)